# Is MPC-HC permanently dead this time? Is there a real alternative? (Last update in mid-2017...)

Tags: windows, media-player

On MPC-HC's website, the last release/news is from "July 16, 2017": 
https://mpc-hc.org/2017/07/16/1.7.13-released-and-farewell/

I'm starting to feel increasingly scared about opening video files in a 2.5 years old media player. Who knows how many exploits have been found in that time?

Anyway, I do have VLC installed, but never use it for playing my video/audio files because:

1. It has no bookmark feature. (It technically does, but since they clear when you close the program, they are about as useful as the hi-score tables in Tetris on Game Boy, which cleared when you switched the handheld off.)
2. It's extremely sluggish at starting up.
3. It feels very non-intuitive to use, even if I admittedly *do* have to set up MPC-HC as well each time I install it.

I really like the simplicity and speed of MPC-HC, but the bookmarks feature is such a massive deal to me (and to everyone else, I would assume) that I simply cannot use VLC. I don't understand what they were thinking with the clearing bookmarks. Makes no sense.

I have heard that there is some "fork" of MPC-HC, but if it's so active and trustworthy, why didn't they get to take over the official MPC-HC website? I don't trust that fork project. I barely trusted the MPC-HC team in the first place, and even that has changed hands several times over the many years I've been using it.

I don't know what to do if I can't even use MPC-HC anymore. It's a very strange feeling to increasingly notice that even the by-far biggest (the **only**, many including myself would say) desktop OS almost has no active/non-dead freeware/FOSS software for extremely common tasks left.

Comment: no, it's not dead. The version on [codecguide](https://codecguide.com/media_player_classic.htm) is constantly updated. But this is off-topic here since this is for software recommendations only

Comment: Welcome MPCHCLover!  Please edit your question and its title to be more on-topic.  We offer software recommendations on this SE.  Thanks!